# How to fetch records for every day in a month using mysql

Tags: mysql

I was working with mysql and i am having a requirement for my reports to get registration data for every day (If search by month) in a month and every month (If search based on a year).

Here is the query i used to get the result

Query:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(tenant_id) AS registered, 
  DATE_FORMAT(created_date,'%d') AS weeks 
FROM asign_user 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(created_date,'%m')='02' 
AND DATE_FORMAT(created_date,'%Y') = '2014' 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_date,'%d');
```

```
-------------------------------
Day       |     Registered
-------------------------------
11                   5
12                   6
13                   1
14                   8
16                   9
25                   15
```

Expected result should be

```
-------------------------------
Day       |     Registered
-------------------------------
01                   0
02                   0
03                   0
04                   0
05                   0
06                   0
.                    .
.                    .
.                    .
.                    .
11                   5
12                   6
13                   1
14                   8
15                   0
16                   9
.                    .  
.                    .
25                   15
.                    .  
.                    .
30/31                0
```

Comment: So? What's the problem?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display (and missing data) at the application level. It's often more efficient.

Comment: Are you saying the numbers are wrong in the original output? I can write the code, but if the numbers are out, I'd need more detail on that first.

Comment: I think the problem is that rows aren't printing out when `Registered` is zero.

Answer (score 0):

i once created an extra table called "all_days", which consisted of all days in a given period( 5years ). you could use that one with an outer-join and then create the output, you desired. I would also advise you to NOT use that approach and do that on the application level( thats what Strawberry said ).
I used that approach in a reporting engine, that didnt allow any application level coding, so that worked for me.... but the result was quite slow :(

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd move the query round slightly to put `weeks` first, so you can use `array_shift` on it.

NOTE: I am writing it in basic MySQL as you do not state if you are using mysql_ or mysqli_ as the connection layer

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT 
      DATE_FORMAT(created_date,'%d') AS weeks 
      COUNT(tenant_id) AS registered, 
    FROM asign_user 
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(created_date,'%m')='02' 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(created_date,'%Y') = '2014' 
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_date,'%d');
SQL;
$run = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($run) > 0)
{
    // Create data
    // This will give the days their registration count.
    $days = array();
    while ($day = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
    {
        $days[array_shift($day)] = $day['registered'];
    }

    // Calculate days in the month
    $month = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 2, 2014);

    // Then loop them and print results
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $month; $i++)
    {
        if (isset($days[$i])) {
            echo "$i : " . $days[$i] . "<br />";
        }
        else {
            echo "$i : 0<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

The above shows days in a month - shouldn't be too hard to edit for monthly :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see this blog, 
http://www.media-division.com/using-mysql-generate-daily-sales-reports-filled-gaps/

The idea is to create a calendar table.

you can also fill the new date date by using cron job and this sql 
INSERT INTO `calendar` ( `datefield` ) VALUES (CURDATE( ))